# Telegram Specific Topic Chat ID

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to get the chat ID of a specific topic within a telegram channel? I have topics enabled and I have a script that I want to post in one of my topics but i can't find a way of getting the chat ID.

I can only seem to get the chat ID for the whole channel, so the messages just go in General rather than each topic.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object has a field `message_thread_id`, that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

View your topic via telegram on the web (web.telegram.org), the chat id for the topic is displayed in the url of your browser when you click on the topic